# Perforce, VisualStudio and Nuget; can't checkout packages

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, nuget, perforce

When I create a new workspace using Perforce, I open my C# VS solution file from within P4V. I then have to reinstall the packages using Update-Package -Reinstall.

However VS keeps asking to save csproj files, which it can't do as Perforce has them marked as Read-only, and VS won't check them out. I could either remove the read-only flag from all my files, which seems a bit heavy handed or I could manually checkout all the files, but there are rather a lot of them. Is there a better solution to this?

Comment: - Do you have the package.config files add into the csproj files?

- Do you have the the perforce visual studio plugin?